# Choosing between template instantiation with pointer arguments

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

Look at the following test code:

```
template<class T> struct Wrap {};

template<typename T> inline
void fun (T *&Int)          // **choice 1**
{}

template<typename T> inline
void fun (Wrap<T> *&Int)    // **choice 2**
{}

int main()
{
  int i = 6;
  fun((char*&)(i));         // **call 1**
  fun((Wrap<char>*&)(i));   // **call 2**
}
```

When I run this code in linux g++, it works as per expectations. When fun() is called with char*&, it calls function of choice 1 straight forward.
However, I am interested when we call fun() with Wrap< char >*& and it calls the choice 2. Even though choice 1 and 2 both appear valid for the 2nd call, compiler manages to choose little better contender -> choice 2 (because it exists).

**Question**: Is it guaranteed that, the same behavior will be retained for any other compiler for C++ ? If not, then is there any other alternative to make it deterministic?

Comment: the `inline` is mostly useless on template functions. It is not necessary because they are (non-specialized) template thus won't cause a linker error and the compiler is much better than us to determine when to inline and when not to... and may perfectly ignore your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the code might look like a template specialization, that is not the case. The language does not allow for partial template function specializations. The two are unrelated templates that happen to be overloads.

The compiler will lookup up the call to `fun( (Wrap<char>*&) i )` with the usual lookup mechanisms, will find the two templates and will determine that there are two potential overloads:

```
template <typename T> void fun( T*& );      // with T == Wrap<char>
template <typename T> void fun( Wrap<T>*& ) // with T == char
```

Overload resolution will then determine that the second is a better match and instantiate it. This is guaranteed by the standard, but beware: they are not the same template, but rather different templates and you might run into undexpected results. Look at the article @LiKao linked for more insight.

Answer (score 6):

The second choice is chosen because it's more specialized than the first- that is, `T*&` can bind to any non-temporary `T*`, but `Wrap<T>*&` can only bind to a non-temporary `Wrap<T>*`. This is Standard as far as I know and should be portable behaviour but what is and isn't portable in practice when it comes to this sort of thing is often not the definition of what's Standard.

Comment: It is in fact portable, but they are not specializations of a template, but rather two separate templates that happen to be overloads.

Answer (score 3):

Someone with a better knowledge of the spec can confirm this, but I believe that as `Wrap<T>` is a more specific type than simply T, call 2 will always resolve to 'choice 2', on all platforms compilers.

Comment: Unless there is a compiler's bug ;)

Comment: Compiler bug!? Never heard of one ... :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might make this even more problematic is, that the rules for specializing template classes and template functions differ a lot. This is do to the possibility of overloading template functions while there is no possibility of overloading classes. Because I am not so firm on this topic I will just link to someone who is able to explain it in more depth:

[Herb Sutter: "Why Not Specialize Function Templates?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: This is not a specialization here, but an overload. A specialization would have a template parameter list appearing between the function identifier and the function arguments (as well as an empty template parameter list appearing after template since function specializations are necessarily full specializations).